# Ionic - Fail on Ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework

I made a tabbed page inside side menu with ionic framework, and run perfectly in PC.
but when i upload it to ionic view (view.ionic.io), and run it on my phone,
the tab disappear.

My Tab Script :

```
<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
     <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
     <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/app/palylist/dash">
       <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>

     <!-- Chats Tab -->
     <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/app/playlist/chats">
       <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>

     <!-- Account Tab -->
     <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/app/playlist/account">
       <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</script>
```

Here i made the complete code in codePen : http://codepen.io/MarcelAng/pen/KrJyYp

Why ?, any idea ?,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the template from app.js by using state / template URL this works for me. Somehow when using script it just doesn't work. Hope this helps

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
```